# Excel vba: detect worksheet switch: when another worksheet gets selected

Tags: excel, vba

Suppose I have a workbook with two worksheets: `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`. I want a message to appear when a user goes from `Sheet2` back to `Sheet1`.

I'm not sure how to approach it - so far I've only been meddling with `Worksheet_Change` sub, but the problem doesn't seem like something that could be solved inside that sub. Right now, I can only think of setting some global variable

```
 Dim previousWorksheet As Variant
 Set previousWorksheet = ActiveSheet.Name
```

And then checking what sheet is the active one:

```
If previousWorksheet = "Sheet2" And ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet1" Then
   MsgBox("DETECTED")

End If
```

But what would trigger that code, I don't know.

What is the best way to accomplish it?

Comment: You can use the [SheetChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetchange) event of the workbook

Comment: @Vincent G Now, I needed `Workbook_SheetActivate`, not `Workbook_SheetChange`.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me (inside ThisWorkbook module):

```
Option Explicit

Dim previousWorksheet As String


Private Sub Workbook_open()
    previousWorksheet = ActiveSheet.Name
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    MsgBox ("changed")

    If ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet1" And previousWorksheet = "Sheet2" Then
        MsgBox ("the switch")

    End If

    previousWorksheet = ActiveSheet.Name

End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need the  () round ("the switch") or ("changed")

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose I have a workbook with two worksheets: Sheet1 and Sheet2

then to get a message

> when a user goes from Sheet2 back to Sheet1

you could simply go:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If Sh.Name = "Sheet1" Then MsgBox "The switch"
End Sub
```